# Is there any better way to do User Input validation in Python3.x ? or Improve this block of code

Tags: python-3.x, validation, user-input

I'm trying to validate multiple user inputs, can be of diff. data types.

Is there any better way to do User Input validation in Python3 ? or Improve this block of code.

```
def validate_number(message):
        i = 0
        while i < 4:
                try:
                        userInput = int(input(message))
                except ValueError:
                        i += 1
                        if i == 4:
                                print('Max try reached !!!')
                                return False
                        else:
                                print("Not an integer! Try again.")
                                continue
                else:
                        return userInput
                        break

#------------------------------------------
a = validate_number('Enter 1st No: ')
if a:
        b = validate_number('Enter 2nd No: ')

if a and b:
        sum = a + b
        print('Result is : %s' %(sum))
        print('Result is : {} '.format(sum))
        print(f'Result is : {sum}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my suggestion:

```
def validate_number(message):
    for i in range(4):
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")
    print("Max try reached !!!")
```

a simple `for` loop in order to count the number of tries.

as it is the function will return `None` if no valid input is given. you may have to tweak that according to your needs.